# ValueError: input_features is not equal to feature_names_in_

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

The python code with the above error is:

```
# categorical columns to encode: Cols_to_encod 
Cols_to_encod = list(X.columns[X.dtypes == 'object'])

# create the transformers
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('onehot', ohe, Cols_to_encod)], remainder='passthrough')

X_transformed = ct.fit_transform(X)

# get the transformed column names
ohe_names = ct.get_feature_names_out(Cols_to_encod)
```

X is training data that is pre-processed to encode categorical columns of X using onehot encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data I cannot confirm this works, but this should fix your problem:

```
# categorical columns to encode: Cols_to_encod 
Cols_to_encod = list(X.columns[X.dtypes == 'object'])

# create the transformers
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('onehot', ohe, Cols_to_encod)], remainder='passthrough')

X_transformed = ct.fit_transform(X)

# get the transformed column names
ohe_names = ct.get_feature_names_out(transformers=[('onehot', ohe, Cols_to_encod)])

# check transformed column names
print("Transformed column names:", ohe_names)
```